# how to parse a xml which might have zero to N number of nodes using perl

Tags: perl, xml, parsing

How to handle a xml which might have one or more occurance of node in the file in perl.

In the current solution provided below,

```
foreach $FileContainerRec (@{$XmlFile->{FileContainer}})
{
    $FileContainer           = 'C'.$FileContainerCt;
     foreach $FileRec (@{$FileContainerRec->{File}}) 
     {
       $File                   = $FileContainer.'file'.$FileCt;
       $OutFileName            = $FileRec->{OutFileName};
       $ActiveIndicator        = $FileRec->{ActiveIndicator};
       $AuditFlag              = $FileRec->{AuditFlag};
       $Delimiter              = $FileRec->{Delimiter};
       @FileDesc=();
       @FileDesc=($OutFileName,$ActiveIndicator,$AuditFlag,$Delimiter);
       $FileList{$File}=[@FileDesc];
       $FileCt++;
     }
     $FileContainerCt++;
     $FileCt=1;
}
```

sample ip xml:

```
<Document>
<FileContainer>
<File>
......
</File>
<File>
......
</File>
</FileContainer>
<FileContainer>
<File>
......
</File>
<File>
......
</File>
</FileContainer>
<Document>
```

the ouccurance of  and  May range from 0 to n number of times.

The perl code snippet throws out error as 'Not an ARRAY Referance', when we have either One 'FileContainer' or 'File' Nodes.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using one of the many XML parsing libraries already available?

Comment: To the close voter, Perl questions are on topic on [su].

Comment: You should avoid `XML::Simple`. The [documentation for the module itself says this](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple): *The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, `XML::LibXML` is highly recommended and `XML::Twig` is an excellent alternative.* If you edit your question to show some usable XML data then I'll write some sample code.

Comment: @mtak: *"Any reason why you're not using one of the many XML parsing libraries already available?"* It looks to me like the OP is using `XML::Simple`.

Comment: We can't really help you without a description of the problem and some valid XML data. ***If you edit your question to show some usable XML data then I'll write some sample code***